# AD FS OAuth - Implicit Grant Flow - How to renew token silently by skipping the Home Realm Discovery page

Tags: javascript, iframe, oauth, adfs, implicit

I am using **ADFS** with the **Implicit Grant Flow** in my SPA to get access tokens,
I'm using **Javascript** and I don't have any access to the **ADFS** configuration.

The first time the user has to log in, he is redirected to the **Home Realm Discovery** page to let him select his **Identity Provider** between 3.

Here is the URL:
`https://.../adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...&nonce=...&redirect_uri=...&resource=...&response_mode=fragment&response_type=token+id_token&scope=...`

Everything works fine but now I have to renew his access token **silently** when it expires.
So I add the `&prompt=none` parameter to the URL, but I get this error:
`Unable+to+handle+the+OAuth+authorization+request+without+getting+user+input.`

I understand that this is because of the **Home Realm Discovery** page, the user has to select his **Identity Provider**.
I've read the documentation but I can't find any way to use the same **Identity Provider** as the first log in.

I've read about the parameter `&domain_hint=...` but I was not able to make it work.
However, I was able to select an **Identity Provider** from the URL thanks to the parameter `&RedirectToIdentityProvider=...`, but I can only select one of them **arbitrary** and not the one used by the user the first time.

Is there a way to **silently renew** the access token, with the `&prompt=none` parameter, by skipping the **Home Realm Discovery** page when a user is already logged in?

Is there any way to receive the selected **Identity Provider** with the response received on the first log in?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There should be refresh token option too by OAuth

Comment: @ArunVishwakarama there is no refresh token when using the Implicit Grant Flow, the workaround is to log in again silently when the access token expires

Comment: What does this question have to do with Realm, aka MongoDB Realm, the database? It's tagged in the question but I don't see the connection??

Comment: @jay nothing related with MongoDB Realm, I don't even know about it
It is about Home Realm Discovery, related to AD FS